# Trying to write a bash script that traps CTRL-C. Upon pressing CTRL-C you are prompted to enter a file

Tags: linux, bash

If you enter a file called 'quit' the script exits. If you enter any other text file, it will return only the lines in the file that start with 'b' or 'B'. Here is my code so far.

[first part of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBZ0r.png)

[second part of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYgL7.png)

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. For reference, I have two text files that I am using. One is blank and is named 'quit' and the other is a random text file with words starting with 'b', 'B' and others that don't start with B. The script should print an asterisk every two seconds. Upon pressing CTRL-C, you are then prompted to enter a file. The script will exit after inputting the 'quit' file or it will display every line starting with 'b' or 'B' upon entering the random word file.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap f1 INT

f1 ()

{

read -p "Enter a filename [enter quit to quit]: " z

cat $z | while read -r line

do

if ((z == "quit"))

then

exit

fi

if [ $z == "^b"* ]

then

echo "$line"

fi

done

}


while true

do

sleep 2 

echo -e "*\c"

done
```

Comment: Put the code inline instead as images.

Comment: You're not checking the user's input for "quit", you are checking for it in the lines you read from the file.

Comment: Also, the `==` operator in bash does not do regular expression matching.  It's going to look for literally the two characters `^b`.  And always remember which variable has the file name and which has a line from the file.

Comment: `cat file | while read` is itself a bad idea -- see [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: And please, **please** indent your code. It's unreadable like this.

Comment: ...beyond that -- don't just show your code and describe what you want it to do; describe a single, specific technical problem, and show only the shortest code that's necessary to test answers to that problem. If your program has two problems, they should be asked as two different questions, each with a [mre] producing only that one problem. (Of course, each such smaller question should be checked for duplicates and asked if it isn't already answered elsewhere in our knowledge base).

Comment: Why are you not using `grep`?  `read; test "$REPLY = quit" && exit 0; grep -i ^b -- "$REPLY";`

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe into a while loop (`cat file.txt | while ....`), you create a subshell.  When you call `exit` within the subshell, only the subshell exits.  The original shell still.... continues on comfortably.  Provide the input via `redirection` to avoid the subshell in this case.

Redirection:

```bash
# This avoids a subshell.
while read line; do
  declare -p line
done < file.txt
# file.txt redirects directly into the while loop

# This avoids a subshell also.
while read line; do
  declare -p line
done < <(echo hello; echo world)
# Process substitution rather than a file.  Just some extra salt to tickle your brain.
```

Lastly, depending on your comfort with some other bash utilities, you can avoid the loop entirely.  `sed` does waay more than just substituting letters or phrases.  `-n` as a `sed` argument means "don't print the lines all the time, only print lines when I tell you to".  `'/pattern/` means that you'll only do the following sed action if the line matches the pattern (in our case, the pattern is `/^b/`).  After the pattern, you could do a `sed` command like `s/from/to/` which is the `s` command that prints.  Or you could do a different command: `p`, which means "just print the line that's being processed" (the line that matched the pattern).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap f1 INT

f1 () {
  read -p "Enter a filename [enter quit to quit]: " z

  # Exit if the user typed "quit".
  [ "$z" == "quit" ] && exit
  
  # Print all the lines that start with "b"
  sed -n '/^b/p' < "$z"
}

# ... other code
```